# Combine multiple tags with a class-name

Tags: html, css

I have these css attributes.

```
table, td, th
{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: green;
}
```

But they should only be applied if table has a special class or id?

```
<table class="mycl">
```

All other tables should not get any of this.

How can I address that in the css?

I tried for class

```
.mycl table, td, th
{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: green;
}
```

but it did not work out. I am not sure how to combine the class with the multiple tags.

*EDIT*

Bases on the the current answers I get to this that does exactly what I want - only format the table with class mycl (and no other) and do it correctly (skip the mycl in the css and see).

```
table.mycl th, table.mycl td, table.mycl
{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color:blue;
}
```

Is there any optimization to that?

Comment: what do you mean by optimization?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
.mycl table
```

Means "a `<table>` which is a child/descendant of an element with the `mycl` class".  To reference a `<table>` which *has* the `mycl` class, you'd combine the two:

```
table.mycl
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if your table has the class "mycl" you can use something like this:

```
.mycl td, .mycl th {
   ... your css styles
}
```

Here you specify that all the elements with class .mycl and have a td tag inside and th inside, should have those styles. But if you write:

```
table, td, th { ... }
```

Your saying that every table, every td tag and every th tag should have those styles.

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect syntax per CSS specificity rules.

Specificity meaning the relevance of the property value you want to apply to an element.

Using `.mycl table` means: apply the following styles to any `.mycl` class and to any `table`

Using `table.mycl` means: apply the following styles to the table who contains the class name `mycl`

If you want to apply a style to the `table` with class `mycl` then you want to use:

```
table.mycl {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: green;
}
```